# When using CreateTable from a class with SQLite in Xamarin is there a way I can have a different name for the table from the class?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here is what I have:

```
public class Note
{
    [PrimaryKey, NotNull]
    public int NotesId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

I am using this statement to create the table:

```
db2.CreateTable<Note>();
```

Is there a way the table can be named "Notes" instead of "Note"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqlite-Net uses the class name to create the table . As a workaround , you could create a subclass of **Note**

```
public class Note
{
    [PrimaryKey, NotNull]
    public int NotesId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class Notes :Note
{
}
```

```
db2.CreateTable<Notes>();
```

Comment: Okay, So there is no way to decorate the Note class?

Comment: I'm afraid that we could not do it , which is  up to the design of sqlite.net .

Comment: Just added another, slightly related question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64008245/when-creating-a-table-in-sqlite-c-sharp-do-i-need-to-create-an-index-on-the-pr