# When creating a table in SQLite C# - Do I need to create an index on the primary key?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

For example on:

```
public class Note
{
    [PrimaryKey, NotNull]
    public string NotesId { get; set; } // Setting this to a GUI
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Do I need to index NoteId or will it automatically be indexed as it is a primary key?

Comment: What means of `index` ? Do you want the NotesId increase automatically ?

Comment: No it's a GUID so I will populate it myself

Comment: This is an SQLite question. While there's no theoretical requirement that a PK is indexed,  databases always index them to speed up uniqueness checks. Otherwise they'd have to scan the entire table to ensure a value is unique

Comment: Data is often stored in PK order in most databases, which makes GUIDs horrible keys as new values may have to be entered at any point in a file, not just the end. This can easily lead to excessive fragmentation. To avoid this you'd probably have to use a sequential UUID algorithm